# How can I display certain rows of a data table?

Tags: database, sqlite, xamarin.forms, datatable

When displaying my CollectionView (which contains the data), I would like to display only the rows that have the field "Number" = xx

Currently I display my data like this:

```
public async Task<List<DB_PosteNF>> ListerPF()
{
  try
  {
     return await connection.Table<DB_PosteNF>().ToListAsync();
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
      StatutMessage = $"Impossible d'afficher la liste des postes de frais. \nErreur : {ex.Message}";
  }
      return new List<DB_PosteNF>();
}
```

Here is the structure of my tables, I would like Primary Key number = Foreign Key

Table 1:
Primary Key = Number

Table 2:
Primary Key = Id
Foreign key = Number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use LINQ

```
connection.Table<DB_PosteNF>().Where(x => x.Number == SomeValue).ToListAsync();
```

Replace `SomeValue` with value you want to filter by